# Removing select items depending on selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select elements with times 12:00 AM through 11:45 PM,

both selects have the same options inside including text and value.  Is it possible for example say I select 1:00 PM on the first select to remove all the options before 1:00 PM on the second select?  I know I can detect the change with jquery

```
$('#select1').change(function(){

// in here do something to remove previous selects

});
```

Any help would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#select1').change(function(){

 var value = $(this).val();
 $("#selectId > option").each(function() {
   if(value > this.value)
      $("#selectId  option[value=this.value]").remove();       
 });    
});
```

But the values need to be in ascending order for select boxes

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of the same where we allow for the user to change his first selection and still filter the second select correctly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var to_mins = function(x) {
    var p = x.split(':').map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10); });
    return (p[0] * 60) + p[1];
  };
  $('#second').data('options', $('#second').find('option').toArray());
  $('#first').change(function() {
     var val = to_mins(this.value);
     console.log(val);
     $('#second').empty();
     $('#second').data('options').filter(function(v) {
       return to_mins(v.value) > val;
     }).map(function(v) {
       $('#second').append(v.cloneNode(true));
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#select1').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $('option:selected', $this).index();
    $('#select2 option').show().filter(':lt(' + index + ')').hide();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UzHtj/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">11h00</option>
  <option value="2">11h15</option>
  <option value="3">11h30</option>
  <option value="4">11h45</option>
  <option value="5">12h00</option>
  <option value="6">12h15</option>
  <option value="7">12h30</option>
  <option value="8">12h45</option>
  <option value="9">13h00</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
   <option value="1">11h00</option>
  <option value="2">11h15</option>
  <option value="3">11h30</option>
  <option value="4">11h45</option>
  <option value="5">12h00</option>
  <option value="6">12h15</option>
  <option value="7">12h30</option>
  <option value="8">12h45</option>
  <option value="9">13h00</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#select1').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').prop('value');

    $('#select2').find('option').show().each(function(){
      if( $(this).prop('value') <= val ){
        $(this).hide();
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```